# Accessing elements from complex repeater in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, repeater

I would like to access the elements from a repeater using protractor.
Normally when the repeater is for example "user in users" i use:
**element(by.repeater("user in users").row(friendNumber))**, so i access the first element from this repeater this way.

But i've faced a more complex repeater - **"user in (offline=(users | orderBy:'username' | filter: {online:false}))"**.
How do I access the elements from this repeater?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can locate this repeater using `by.repeater` or `by.exactRepeater` and, according to the protractor core developers noted in a [github issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2434) while discussing a similar problem:

> I don't think we should get into the business of syntax parsing for
>   Angular, as it'll be a maintainability nightmare.

Use a `by.css` locator instead, for example:

```
$$("[ng-repeat*=offline]");
```